# Do you keep your project code names the same in the source tree?

Tags: project-structure

Sometimes when I start working on a project, I just can't think of a good name, or think of a good name that isn't already taken. As a result, I'll end up picking some sort of code name for the project.

My question is, how do you handle name changes in your source code once you find a real name for your project? Should you continue to refer to the code name in your source tree, namespaces, binaries, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, it is extremely common that the name used to market a product is completely different from the name used internally for that product by the developers. Most often, because marketing has not decided on a name yet when development starts.

Whenever a project or product name is used in the internal documentation, file hierarchy, etc., it has been the practice to keep using the internal code-name, even after marketing has decided on the official product name. Only in documentation that is meant for the end-users is the product referred to with its official marketing name.
Usually, there is significant cost and no benefit in renaming everything.